# How to populate an array from data in a table

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays

I'm writing a very simple seating plan arranger. I have a database with a list of people attending and each has a table number assigned (`$tano`)

My PHP is as follows:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $con) or die(mysql_error());

// Get current table no
$tableno = $_GET["t"];
    
// Current table -> array
$t = array();
$i = 0;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM plan WHERE tano = $tableno ORDER BY fname');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$t[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}
    
// Get other tables (Seats Remaining)
for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plan WHERE 'tano' = $i");
    $seatsremaining = 10-mysql_num_rows($result);
         if ($seatsremaining == 0) {$d[$i] = "Table ".$i." (No Seats Remaining)";}
    else if ($seatsremaining == 1) {$d[$i] = "Table ".$i." (1 Seat Remaining)";}
    else if ($seatsremaining >= 2) {$d[$i] = "Table ".$i." (".$seatsremaining." Seats Remaining)";}
}

?>
```

The array is not populated and it generates an SQL error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/greenbot/public_html/index.php on line 18

The table structure is:

[image]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM plan WHERE 'tano' = $i` ?
If tano is a field name then it should delimited by `
' makes it a string literal.

Like george mentioned, sharing the exact error message helps.

Comment: also.. I've tried it with and without the quotation marks.

Comment: Can you also share the table structure?

Comment: Gotta a debug a bit here. Can you replace
// Get current table no
$tableno = $_GET["t"];

// Current table -> array
$t = array();
$i = 0;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM plan WHERE tano = $tableno ORDER BY fname');

with

// Get current table no
$tableno = $_GET["t"];
echo 'tableno: ' . $tableno;
// Current table -> array
$t = array();
$i = 0;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM plan WHERE tano = $tableno ORDER BY fname');
echo mysql_error();

Let me know what you see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Sorry about the delay.. I've uploaded the new code. Same result still.  No change in error message either...?

Comment: I feel I should also add that line 18 (The one it claims has an error) is simply "$t[$i] = $row;"

Comment: @Pete, you'll need to add the updated code to the end of your question _here_. If you only upload it to your site, we won't see it and the question will not help future users of the site.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I've not changed my code at all. It still isn't fixed. All I did was add the error capturing and tried everyone's ideas. None of that changed anything :(

Comment: @Pete, I'll give this a last try. You said "I've uploaded the new code." That is the code that you need to upload here. Let us check that change is as expected. If you have indeed added the `...or die(mysql_error())` statement in the right place, the error _will_ change. If it is in the wrong place, we can help you add it correctly.

Comment: Well.. I added it on the end of the sql statement and it did nothing.. none the less.. my problem was that my array started at 0 and not 1.. as there is no table 0, it failed. It's all working now.

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, you are missing quotes around your value:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM plan WHERE tano = $tableno ORDER BY fname');
```

This should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plan WHERE tano = '$tableno' ORDER BY fname");
```

In your second query, you are using quotes instead of backticks around the column name:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plan WHERE 'tano' = $i");
```

This should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plan WHERE `tano` = $i");
```

You should note that your code assumes that the query completed successfully instead of checking. For debugging purposes, you can add:

```
... or die(mysql_error());
```

to the end of each of your `mysql_query(...)` statements to get details about the attempted queries. You should develop a logging strategy for such errors in production code.

Additionally, be aware that using unfiltered user input `$tableno = $_GET["t"];` opens the door for SQL injection attacks. Consider updating your code to use parameterized PDO queries, or at least filter your incoming data.

Comment: What do you have against single quotes?

Comment: Oh, nvm, that's a field name. Why even put backticks instead of just nothing?

Comment: Backticks prevent MySQL from interpreting the column name as a keyword in cases where there is a conflict. Table names can also be treated the same way.

Comment: @Pete, you're going to have to be more specific. What errors do you get when you incorporate the `or die(mysql_error());` statements into your code? Please add these details to your original post.